# I woul like to Reduce MYSQL Query Execution time.my query taking long time?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, query-optimization, execution

Following MYSQL Query Taking Long Time To Execute How to reduce execution time any solution? The table contains more than 1000 records I am trying to update sort order (prd_sort_order) based on price (prd_price) in a product table

SQl:-

```
SET @rank = 0;
    UPDATE tbl_products p SET p.prd_sort_order=@rank:=@rank+1
     WHERE p.prd_booking_status=1 
       AND p.prd_status=1
     ORDER BY p.prd_price DESC
```

Comment: With respect, this isn't an SQL query, it's a php function that uses several SQL queries. Please [edit] your post to show us the SQL queries themselves; that will help you get better answers. And, what version of MySQL is involved?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: How to reduce Execution time? it takes long time to execute

Comment: What is "it"? Which of these queries is slow? And what have you tried to make it faster?

Comment: SET @rank = 0;
    UPDATE tbl_products p SET p.prd_sort_order=@rank:=@rank+1
     WHERE p.prd_booking_status=1 
       AND p.prd_status=1
     ORDER BY p.prd_price DESC

Comment: **What have you tried to debug the problem**? What does the execution plan tell you?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your code uses queries following this pattern:

```sql
SET @rank = something;

UPDATE tbl p SET p.prd_sort_order=@rank:=@rank+1
 WHERE p.prd_booking_status=1 
   AND p.prd_status=1
 ORDER BY p.prd_price DESC
 
SELECT MAX(prd_sort_order) as prd_sort_order FROM tbl
 WHERE prd_booking_status = 1
   AND prd_status=1
```

Your update queries will be helped a lot by a particular compound index on your table. You can create it, from a sql client like phpmyadmin, like this.

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_price_sort_order 
          ON tbl (booking_status, prd_status, prd_price DESC);
```

This works because your queries can random-access the index to the first row with matching booking and prd status, then read the index sequentially to get the rows in the correct order.

Similarly, your select queries can use this index.

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_prd_sort_order 
          ON tbl (booking_status, prd_status, prd_sort_order DESC);
```

Beware: If two users run this php program concurrently, you're likely to get rubbish. Try starting this sequence of queries with `START TRANSACTION;` and ending it with `COMMIT;` to avoid concurrency confusion.

How did I work out this question?

1. I isolated the SQL queries from all the php stuff. I wish you had done that, but it doesn't matter.
2. I looked for a common pattern of WHERE and ORDER BY between them.
3. I used my [knowledge of database indexes](https://use-the-index-luke.com/), from Marcus Windand's online book, to figure out an index that will help you.

You can do this sort of thing yourself in future. The point of StackOverflow is to make people self-sufficient.

And, it has to be said, the way this application is designed, **it can't ever be very fast**. This code updates a significant fraction of the rows in your table every time it runs, and that takes time. **As your table gets bigger, it takes more time: O(n). That's not good.** You're much better off doing this price-ranking work in the SELECT queries you use when you look up stuff from the tables. Feel free to ask another question.